# Core Graphics Games performances on Real Devices

Tags: ios, performance, swift, uikit, core-graphics

I create Graphics for simple game with Core graphics using swift and UIKit with Interval = 0.03. It's about ~ 30FPS

```
class CView: UIView {
let img = UIImage(named: "background.png")
func initalize(){
            var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.03, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func update(){
        setNeedsDisplay();
    }

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect){
 img?.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
}

}
```

In ViewController 's class, i'm using fullscreen scale with all devices

```
let mainview = CView()
        mainview.initalize()
        var rect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        var scaleX = rect.width / 480;
        var scaleY = rect.height / 800;
        mainview.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, scaleX, scaleY);
        view = mainview
```

It's working fine with Simulator with 30FPS, but it's just 5-8 FPS on Real Devices (IPhone 4S, Iphone 4), 10-14FPS(Iphone 5,5s). So, how to get better performance on real phone. 
I just draw one Image, so I wanted to draw more Image with the best performance. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a horrible way to do things, you really should look into more appropriate frameworks, such as [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

I am not a game developer myself, but using NSTimer seems like a bad idea, especially if performance is of any importance. In short, you should rethink the logic of when and how the screen is redrawn, instead of forcing a redraw every x ms, let the system handle deciding this for you, for example, if you were animating something using CoreAnimation, the system would be only redrawing parts of the screen etc.

In short, read up on game engines and potentially rethink your approach, good luck!